# Speed up the calculation of squared error for large arrays in R

Tags: r, runtime

Basically I am helping someone to write some code for their research, but my usual time saving tactics have not reduced the run time of her algorithm enough for it to be reasonable.  I was hoping someone else might know a better way to make a function run quickly based on an example I have written to avoid including information about the research.

The object in the example is smaller than the one she is using (but can easily be made larger).  For the actual algorithm, this piece takes about 3 minutes in a small case, but might take 8-10 in the full case, and needs to run probably 1000-10000 times.  This is the reason I need to seriously reduce the run time.

How I am currently doing this (hopefully with enough comments to make my thought process obvious):

```
example<-array(rnorm(100000), dim=c(5, 25, 40, 20))

observation <- array(rnorm(600), dim=c(5, 5, 12))

calc.err<-function(value, observation){
  #'This creates the squared error for each observation, and each point in the
  #'example array, across the five values in the first dimension of each

  sqError<-(value-observation)^2

  #'the apply function here sums up the squared error for each observation and
  #'point.  This is the value returned

  return(apply(sqError, c(2,3), function(x) sum(x)))
}

run<-apply(example, c(2,3,4), function(x) calc.err(x, observation))

#'It isn't returned in the right format (small problem) but reformatting is fast
format<-array(run, dim=c(5, 12, 25, 40, 20))
```

Will clarify if necessary.

edit:
The data.table package appears to be very helpful. I will have to learn that package, but preliminaries seem to be much faster. I guess I was working with arrays because the code she gave me to make faster had the objects formatted that way. Didn't even think about changing it

Comment: I would not work with arrays for this. I would transform the data to long-format data.tables and use package data.table to aggregate by groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple simple refactors along with the timings:

```
calc.err2 <- function(value, observation){
  #'This creates the squared error for each observation, and each point in the
  #'example array, across the five values in the first dimension of each

  sqError<-(value-observation)^2

  #' getting rid of the anonymous function

  apply(sqError, c(2,3), sum)
}

calc.err3 <- function(value, observation){
  #'This creates the squared error for each observation, and each point in the
  #'example array, across the five values in the first dimension of each

  sqError<-(value-observation)^2

  #' replacing with colSums

  colSums(sqError)
}


R>microbenchmark(times=8, apply(example, 2:4, calc.err, observation),
+   apply(example, 2:4, calc.err2, observation),
+   apply(example, 2:4, calc.err3, observation)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr         min          lq
  apply(example, 2:4, calc.err, observation) 2284.350162 2321.875878
 apply(example, 2:4, calc.err2, observation) 2194.316755 2257.007572
 apply(example, 2:4, calc.err3, observation)  645.004808  652.567611
         mean       median           uq         max neval
 2349.7524509 2336.6661645 2393.3452420 2409.894876     8
 2301.7896566 2298.9346090 2362.5479790 2383.020177     8
  681.3176878  667.9070175  720.7049605  723.177516     8
```

`colSums` is way faster than the corresponding `apply`.